# Formal way of saying "I'm on it"

Tags: expressions, formality

Want to answer to my supervisor's question about the status of a task. What come's to my mind is "I'm on it". What's a more formal way of saying that?

Comment: Do you want to avoid communicating a timeframe for completing the task?  "I'm on it" is half a status report, if you ask me.

Comment: How's your answer coming along? "Consider it done."

Comment: Define "*formal*".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Examples:

> I'm about two-thirds of the way through the project.
>
> It is my top priority at this time.
>
> I'm working on other projects at the moment, but if you would like, I'll set them aside and focus on this task instead; just let me know.
>
> I estimate I'll finish that task within the next two hours.

The more specific the update you can offer, the better the response will be received.

Comment: +1  Managers ultimately want to know when it will be finished. Just saying, “I’m on it” or it’s equivalent tells them virtually nothing and would probably inwardly frustrate the manager.

Comment: Maybe it's just me but the latter three phrases don't sound very good in spoken English.. very robotic.

Comment: @Insane Well, they're not spoken, they're written ;-)

Comment: @Insane- "You will no longer be alone. You will no longer feel fear. You will no longer have any worries. You will be able to adapt to any problems. You will be assimilated. Resistance is futile."

Answer (score 4):

Here's one:

> It's **underway** and should be done within (estimated time to completion).
>
> **un·der·way**
>
> adverb
>
> having started and in progress; being done or carried out.

Answer (score 2):

You could say *I'm working on it [as we speak](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/as+we+speak)*.

> **As we speak:** just now; at this very moment

TFD

Answer (score 1):

An example of what you could say:

> I'm currently working on this task and expect to be finished with it by the end of next week.

Answer (score 1):

***“I'll see to it immediately.”***

***“I'll see to that right away Mrs. Johnson.”***

These equate to a more formal *“I'm on it”*, if that can help you.  But, as the managerial types have so smugly announced above, that is not sufficient for a *“**status** report”* of a task already assigned some time prior, which by modern practice should include an estimated time of completion, all things considered.